# SQL using SUM first then MAX functions to find result set

Tags: sql

Been having a hard time finding a subquery to work.  The data set is simple.  Below dealership owner has recorded sales based on model.  Need to find the sum and group by of car, year, sold (which I can do) but then need to get the max model for the year.  Looking for any assistance.

Initial sql to get the sum count with group by was..

Select car, year, sum(sold)
From sales
Group By car, year

Then needing to find the max sold for each year.  I've tried this below but my sub query syntax isn't working.

select car, year, max(sold)
from ( select car, year, sum(sold) from sales s group by car, year) as x

```
|car        | year   | sold        | state    |
-----------------------------------------------
|  chevy    |2019    | 1004        | IL       |
|  chevy    |2019    |  2005       | MO       |
|  chevy    |2019    |  900        | AZ       |
|  honda    |2019    |  1200       | OH       |
|  honda    |2019    |  1116       | MO       |
|  honda    |2019    |  1300       | AZ       |
|  mitsu    |2020    |  500        | IL       |
|  mitsu    |2020    |  200        | MO       |
|  mitsu    |2020    |  400        | AZ       |
|  ford     |2020    |  2000       | OH       |
|  ford     |2020    |  3000       | MO       |
|  ford     |2020    |  2222       | AZ       |
```

---

```
| car       | year   | sold        |
------------------------------------
|  honda    |2019    |  3616       |
|  ford     |2020    |  7222       |
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: what does `max model of year` mean ? also please provide desired output and show us your try

Comment: My apologies, I have written several iterations of queries.  Will post some examples shortly.  Expected result set is the 2nd table posted on bottom that has 2 records.  First I did a sum on sold that got the total for each group but then I want the max record for the car sold for year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to sum things up.  Then use window functions:

```
select car, year, sold
from (select car, year, sum(sold) as sold,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by sum(sold) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by car, year
     ) cy
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon, many many thanks!  Been trying for days on this and your agg worked.  Will do better with my next question with more detail admins.